# how to get External group or member from google groups API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, issue-tracking, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I am using the Workspace admin SDK, Directory API I get the internal groups and their member but the need is we need to get the External organization group and its member by using google groups API.

Can you please share the information or link on how to get the external group and its members by using google groups api?

For more information,I provide link over here,
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Google Groups (https://groups.google.com/)? Google Workspace does not provide an API for that service. Edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Workspace Admin SDK > Directory API: Groups will not list external groups as external groups are only visible through groups.google.com and unfortunately there is no API for Google Groups.